# Python 3, unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Tags: python-3.7

I am freshman in this sphere, so please help.

```
import pygal
line_chart = pygal.Line()
line_chart.title="Chart"
line_chart.x_labels = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'April', 'May']
print('Enter a type of social media: ')
a=input()
print('Enter 5 values of '+a,': ')
b=list(input())
line_chart.add(a, b)
line_chart.render_in_browser()
```

**Exception has occurred: TypeError
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'**
this error is appearing in front of *line_chart.render_in_browser()* this code

Comment: Result of `input()` is a string, yes?

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing `str` type of data into your chart.

You have to convert your `input` type. The line chard would work on `int`, `float` or decimal type for number.

```
import pygal 
line_chart = pygal.Line() 
line_chart.title="Chart" 
line_chart.x_labels = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'April', 'May'] 
print('Enter a type of social media: ') 
a=input() 
print('Enter 5 values of '+a,': ') 
b=map(int, input().split())
line_chart.add(a, list(b)) 
line_chart.render_in_browser()
```

Comment: did it work when you tried? because in my situation now it is appearing another error, when i did as you showed

Comment: Its working for me, and what is the error? Also share your inputs.
for me input was `a = test` and `b = 1 2 3 4 5`

Comment: i inputted values then, invalid literal for int() with base 10: '23,' this appeared. (here 23 is one of my values)

Comment: try without comma `,` `1 2 3 4 5`